# There is no iOS application in xcode target

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

I just accidentally remove my app's entitlements and I realized that only Watch OS apps is available on the Target section !!!! there ins no main application at all ! I tried to add main iOS application from `scheme` menu  but there is nothing only WatchKit app  ! [image]

What is the solution !?? Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

File -> new -> Target -> IOS Application -> check the target in the File Inspector for your files